# Leaflet w/ ajax clustering

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i am using leaflet and wanted to add the MarkerCluster plugin.

So far i have a working code that adds markers to a map and adds them to layers.

The following code builds the markers and layers from a database.

```
    <?php include("cliente/config.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" />

<title>::: C24 :::</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hsd-flotr2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pushy.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leaflet/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="flotr2.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

function onClick(e) {
    alert(this.getLatLng());
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());


$lat = '-39.55660675652325';
$lon = '-72.92878048494458';

$zoom = 7;

$pr = "";
$abc = "";
$abd = "";
$abe = "";


$k = 1;
$v = 'p';
$t = 't';
$w = '_';

$query_11 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT zona FROM alarm;");
while($info_11 = mysql_fetch_array($query_11)) {

    $i=1;
    $query_1 = mysql_query("SELECT lat, lon FROM alarm WHERE zona = '$info_11[0]' LIMIT 100;");
    While($info_1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_1)) {

        $abc .= "var ";
        $abc .= "$v$k$w$i";
        $abc .= "= L.marker([";
        $abc .= "$info_1[0],$info_1[1]";
        $abc .= "]).on('mouseover', onClick);";

        $i++;
        }

$abd .= "var t".$k." = L.markerClusterGroup([";

for ($x=1; $x<$i; $x++) {
$abd .= "$v$k$w$x,";
}

$abd .= "]);";

$k++;
}

$l=1;
$abe .= "var overlayMaps = {";

$query_22 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT zona FROM alarm;");
while($info_22 = mysql_fetch_array($query_22)) {

    $abe .= "\"$info_22[0]\": t$l,";

$l++;
}
$abe .= "};";

//________________________________________________________________________________________________wie immer ab hier
echo"
<div id='map' style='width: 800px; height: 400px;background:#EEEEEE;'></div>
";

echo"
<script>
function initmap() {
var map;
map = new L.Map('map');
var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='';
var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl,{minZoom:4,maxZoom:20,attribution:osmAttrib});

var hull = new L.LatLng('-36.826382900000000','-73.042523000000000');

map.setView(hull,12);
map.addLayer(osm);

$abc

$abd

$abe

L.control.layers(overlayMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
}

initmap();
</script>
";

mysql_close($con);

?>      
</body>
</html>
```

The page on github states that to initiate cluster option you have to add the CSS and JS files witch are on the main page calling tha map via ajax.

The examples i found so far and do not use angular.leaflet state the following use

```
var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i )
{

  var m = L.marker([markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng])
                  .bindPopup( popup );

  markerClusters.addLayer( m );
}
 map.addLayer(markerClusters);
```

how can i adapt this.
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides loading the [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin CSS and JS files after Leaflet ones, simply replace your:

```
L.layerGroup(markersArray)
```

by:

```
L.markerClusterGroup().addLayers(markersArray)
```

Note that there is a slight difference between initialization of [Layer Groups](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup), which can directly receive an array of Markers as argument, and MarkerClusterGroup, which must be initialized first, then you can add an array of markers with its [`addLayers`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#bulk-adding-and-removing-markers) method.

Example:

```js
function abc_fillMarkers() {
  for (var zoneK = 0; zoneK < 3; zoneK += 1) {
    markersPzoneK_indexI[zoneK] = [];

    for (var markerIndexI = 0; markerIndexI < 20; markerIndexI += 1) {
      markersPzoneK_indexI[zoneK].push(
        L.marker(getRandomLatLng())
      );
    }
  }
}

function abd_fillGroups() {
  for (var zoneK = 0; zoneK < 3; zoneK += 1) {
    groupsTzoneK[zoneK] = L.markerClusterGroup().addLayers(markersPzoneK_indexI[zoneK]);
  }
}

function abe_fillOverlays() {
  for (var zoneK = 0; zoneK < 3; zoneK += 1) {
    overlayMaps['Group ' + zoneK] = groupsTzoneK[zoneK];
  }
}

function initmap() {
  var map;
  map = new L.Map('map');
  var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
  var osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
  var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: osmAttrib
  });

  hull = new L.LatLng('-36.826382900000000', '-73.042523000000000');

  map.setView(hull, 12);
  map.addLayer(osm);

  //$abc
  abc_fillMarkers();

  //$abd
  abd_fillGroups();

  //$abe
  abe_fillOverlays();

  L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps, {
    collapsed: false
  }).addTo(map);

  // Add to map all groups initially.
  Object.values(overlayMaps).forEach(function(overlay) {
    overlay.addTo(map);
  });
}

var hull;
var markersPzoneK_indexI = {};
var groupsTzoneK = {};
var overlayMaps = {};

initmap();

function getRandomLatLng() {
  return [
    hull.lat - 0.05 + 0.1 * Math.random(),
    hull.lng - 0.1 + 0.2 * Math.random()
  ];
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.markercluster assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it did not work for me. As soon as i try to display the layer with the markers it does not load.

Comment: y put all in one file and it loads my markers with L.layerGroup but not with L.markerClusterGroup

Comment: My bad, my explanation was not explicit enough. With Leaflet.markercluster, you cannot directly add your array of Markers as 1st argument of `L.markerClusterGroup`. You have to initialize it first, then use its `addLayers` method. See the edited answer.

Comment: thanks alot know i understood and could implement it